# How to visualize binary data?

Tags: matlab, binary, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset 6x1000 of binary data (6 data points, 1000 boolean dimensions).

I perform cluster analysis on it

```
[idx, ctrs] = kmeans(x, 3, 'distance', 'hamming');
```

And I get the three clusters. How can I visualize my result?

I have 6 rows of data each having 1000 attributes; 3 of them should be alike or similar in a way. Applying clustering will reveal the clusters. Since I know the number of clusters
I only need to find similar rows. Hamming distance tell us the similarity between rows and the result is correct that there are 3 clusters.

> [EDIT: for any reasonable data, kmeans will always finds asked number
> of clusters]

I want to take that knowledge
and make it easily observable and understandable without having to write huge explanations.

Matlab's example is not suitable since it deals with numerical 2D data while my questions concerns n-dimensional categorical data.

The dataset is here http://pastebin.com/cEWJfrAR

> [EDIT1: how to check if clusters are significant?]

For more information please visit the following link:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32090/discussion-between-oleg-komarov-and-justcurious

If the question is not clear ask, for anything you are missing.

Comment: Which part of the example in the docs of  `kmeans()` you do not like?

Comment: plot(X(idx==1,1),X(idx==1,2),'r.','MarkerSize',12)
hold on
plot(X(idx==2,1),X(idx==2,2),'b.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'kx',...
     'MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'ko',...
     'MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
legend('Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Centroids',...
       'Location','NW') concerns 2D data with X = [randn(100,2)+ones(100,2);...
     randn(100,2)-ones(100,2)]; which is far from what I have... Is that what you mean?

Comment: Try then to use `spy` and place the cluster centroids.

Comment: I get a straight line from 1 to 1000....

Comment: `spy(x)` an you get a line?

Comment: with nz=1748. Matlab's example refer to a simple problem with 200x2 dimensions of non-binary data. If it is trivial for you, could you please provide an example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32090/discussion-between-oleg-komarov-and-justcurious)

Comment: You might want to perform your `kmeans` on `x'`? (That's the transposed version of x).

Comment: Please post the code that generates your sample.data

Comment: what is that for? Why does this matter? It's written in Java. basically it creates random sequences of binary numbers but for a predefined portion of the sequences it modifies a part. e.g 1010111111 and 1110111111 belong to the same category since the only difference is a single bit. Does this give you the information you need about the data?

Comment: why this post has been down voted? Does anyone has a suggestion then?

Comment: You need to provide a Minimum Working Example, without too much effort from the answerer. I was interested in your question, copy pasting all that unformatted data is simply NOT feasible.

Comment: Your question gets down-voted because it is not very clear what you are trying to do. The documentation offers an example on how to visualize data. If that doesn't work for you, you should have included that in your question with a comment on why I does not apply to your situation. Providing background on why you are doing what you are doing allows for answers "outside the box" - maybe your approach is not the best for the problem at hand. Finally: Consider [this website on how to ask good questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: they are not unformatted. pasting to matlab creates the 6 by 1000 matrix. here is a link to the txt used http://www.4shared.com/office/az6uaIEP/random.html?

Comment: the problem is explained in the chat. Please let me know if it is not accessible or if more info is needed.

Comment: Your question should be as self-contained as possible and not require people to read a lot of external sources.

Comment: I updated the description with what i feel more important. Please let me know if it is fine. Please let me know of any suggestions to the problem.

Comment: I do not have a 4shared account, can you post smt of the form data = [........]; into pastebin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rA2Zcx4L

Comment: @JustCurious Instead of the copy-pasting your actual data, can't you provided a short code snippet resembling `x = rand(6, 1000) > 0.5` that can be used instead?

Comment: This is an important question, I agree it needs editing though. Most importantly what is the physical source of that data? Are attributes expected to be independent?

Answer (score 6):

For representing the differences between high-dimensional vectors or clusters, I have used Matlab's `dendrogram` function. For instance, after loading your dataset into the matrix `x` I ran the following code:

```
l = linkage(a, 'average');
dendrogram(l);
```

and got the following plot:

[image: Dendrogram plot of your dataset]

The height of the bar that connects two groups of nodes represents the average distance between members of those two groups. In this case it looks like (5 and 6), (1 and 2), and (3 and 4) are clustered.

If you would rather use the hamming distance rather than the euclidian distance (which `linkage` does by default), then you can just do

```
l = linkage(x, 'average', {'hamming'});
```

although it makes little difference to the plot.

Answer (score 5):

You can start by visualizing your data with a 'barcode' plot and then labeling rows with the cluster group they belong:

```
% Create figure
figure('pos',[100,300,640,150])

% Calculate patch xy coordinates
[r,c] = find(A);
Y = bsxfun(@minus,r,[.5,-.5,-.5, .5])';
X = bsxfun(@minus,c,[.5, .5,-.5,-.5])';

% plot patch
patch(X,Y,ones(size(X)),'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','k');

% Set axis prop
set(gca,'pos',[0.05,0.05,.9,.9],'ylim',[0.5 6.5],'xlim',[0.5 1000.5],'xtick',[],'ytick',1:6,'ydir','reverse')

% Cluster
c = kmeans(A,3,'distance','hamming');

% Add lateral labeling of the clusters
nc   = numel(c);
h    = text(repmat(1010,nc,1),1:nc,reshape(sprintf('%3d',c),3,numel(c))');
cmap = hsv(max(c));
set(h,{'Background'},num2cell(cmap(c,:),2))
```

[image]

Comment: But it also shows that it is difficult to learn anything by inspecting it visually.

Comment: @Hugues Exactly, that is why I personally liked a lot the dendrogram.

Comment: I copied paste your code and i get something different. There are not numbers in the boxes on the right hand side. What data did u use. It puts everything under one cluster... "A" is the raw data right?

Comment: I call the `A` data that I got from pastebin. I copy-paste the data, put some `[]` brackets around it, and assign to `A = [...];`. Then running the code above everything runs fine.

Comment: for a strange reason...i do the same but my results are different. Firstly, there is no number on top of the coloured square on the right hand side and secondly all 6 have the same colour. Did i forget something? I just copied pasted ur code and use my data as follows: `load random.txt
data=random;
A=[data];` also tried `A=random` directly...

Comment: try to copy paste from pastebin. I replaced the link with a ready to copy paste execute version of data (no changes were introduced).

Answer (score 4):

**Definition**

The Hamming distance for binary strings a and b the Hamming distance is equal to the number of ones (population count) in a XOR b (see [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)).

**Solution**

Since you have six data strings, so you could create a 6 by 6 matrix filled with the Hamming distance. The matrix would be symetric (distance from a to b is the same as distance from b to a) and the diagonal is 0 (distance for a to itself is nul).

For example, the Hamming distance between your first and second string is:

```
hamming_dist12 = sum(xor(x(1,:),x(2,:)));
```

Loop that and fill your matrix:

```
hamming_dist = zeros(6);
for i=1:6,
  for j=1:6,
    hamming_dist(i,j) = sum(xor(x(i,:),x(j,:)));
  end
end
```

(And yes this code is a redundant given the symmetry and zero diagonal, but the computation is minimal and optimizing not worth the effort).

Print your matrix as a spreadsheet in text format, and let the reader find which data string is similar to which.

This does not use your "kmeans" approach, but your added description regarding the problem helped shaping this out-of-the-box answer. I hope it helps.

---

**Results**

```
    0  182  481  495  490  500
  182    0  479  489  492  488
  481  479    0  180  497  517
  495  489  180    0  503  515
  490  492  497  503    0  174
  500  488  517  515  174    0
```

Edit 1:

How to read the table? The table is a simple [distance table](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&q=%22%20distance%20table). Each row and each column represent a series of data (herein a binary string). The value at the intersection of row 1 and column 2 is the Hamming distance between string 1 and string 2, which is 182. The distance between string 1 and 2 is the same as between string 2 and 1, this is why the matrix is symmetric.

---

**Data analysis**

Three clusters can readily be identified: 1-2, 3-4 and 5-6, whose Hamming distance are, respectively, 182, 180, and 174.
Within a cluster, the data has ~18% dissimilarity. By contrast, data not part of a cluster has ~50% dissimilarity (which is random given binary data).

Comment: how did u do the data analysis? how did u figure out the classes?

Comment: I clarified the **distance table** idea in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Presentation**

I recommend [Kohonen network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map) or similar technique to present your data in, say, 2 dimensions. In general this area is called [Dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction).

I you can also go simpler way, e.g. [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), but there's no quarantee you can effectively remove 9998 dimensions :P

[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) is a good Python package to get you started, similar exist in matlab, java, ect. I can assure you it's rather easy to implement some of these algorithms yourself.

**Concerns**

I have a concern over your data set though. 6 data points is really a small number. moreover your attributes seem boolean at first glance, if that's the case, manhattan distance if what you should use. I think (someone correct me if I'm wrong) Hamming distance only makes sense if your attributes are somehow related, e.g. if attributes are actually a 1000-bit long binary string rather than 1000 independent 1-bit attributes.

Moreover, with 6 data points, you have only 2 ** 6 combinations, that means 936 out of 1000 attributes you have are either truly redundant or indistinguishable from redundant.

`K-means` almost always finds as many clusters as you ask for. To test significance of your clusters, run K-means several times with different initial conditions and check if you get same clusters. If you get different clusters every time or even from time to time, you cannot really trust your result.

Answer (score 0):

I used a barcode type visualization for my data. The code which was posted here earlier by Oleg was too heavy for my solution (image files were over 500 kb) so I used image() to make the figures

```
function barcode(A)
B = (A+1)*2;
image(B);
colormap flag;

set(gca,'Ydir','Normal')    
axis([0 size(B,2) 0 size(B,1)]);
ax = gca;
ax.TickDir = 'out'

end
```